# Proper use of verb GRANT

Tags: verbs

According to oxford advanced learner's **grant sth to somebody** is correct. 
But in the following sentence **grant sth for sb** is used .
 The U.S. has been urging China to increase market access and **grant intellectual property protections for American corporations**, cut back on industrial subsidies and, at a broader level, bring down the $375-billion trade gap. 
 Is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

With *to* (grant something to somebody) the preposition phrase is a complement of the verb: *to somebody* designates the recipient of the grant.

There are several ways of analyzing the sentence you quote; but the preposition phrase headed by *for* is not a complement of the verb in any.

1. The PP is a constituent of the object noun phrase: *for American corporations* modifies *intellectual property protections*. The corporations are beneficiaries of the protections, not recipients of the grant.
2. The PP is a modifier of both object noun phrases: the corporations are beneficiaries of both the market access and the protections.
3. The PP is a modifier of the conjunct verb phrases: the corporations are beneficiaries of both the increase and the grant.

The recipient of the grant is not named under either analysis; presumably it would be the US.

It doesn't really matter how you analyze it, and I doubt that the writer gave much thought to expressing his thought with technical precision; they all amount to pretty much the same thing, which is that the US is urging China to do things which will benefit American corporations.